# Exists a list where every item is a member?

Tags: python, list, membership

I'm currently trying to write an abstraction for some Spark Streaming jobs that each have a portion of code which the the same between all of them (hence the need for an abstraction).

The format of each job is in this format:

```
dStream \
        .filter(lambda rec: rec[self.EVENT_KEY_VALUE[0]] in list(self.EVENT_KEY_VALUE[1])) \
        .filter(lambda rec: self.EVENT_FIELDS.issubset(set(rec.keys()))) \

for INPUT in INPUTS:
        dStream \
            .map(lambda rdd: format_record_keys_for_salesforce(self.INPUT))

for map_func in OPTIONAL_MAPS:
        dStream \
            .map(map_func)

return dStream.map(self.OUTPUT.project_row)
```

There is always a `format_record_keys_for_salesforce` map stage and always a `dStream.map(self.OUTPUT.project_row)` stage. The problem comes from the first two `filter()`s. There is almost always the two filter stages in in each job however sometimes the job does not require it. I would rather have the filters be redundant and do nothing but return `True` than have a dev have to write extra code.

So, how can I write a `list` where any arbitrary value is a member of it? We do not know the values beforehand, only that it is a member of the list.

Kind of like:

```
>> 'a' in list(all)
True
>> 5 in list(all)
True
>> *anything* in list(all)
True
>> ALL_NATURAL_NUMBERS in list(all)
True
>> ALL_SUBSETS_OF_NATURAL_NUMBERS in list(all)
True 
etc...
```

Is this possible or will I have to remove those stages from my abstraction and leave it up to the dev writing to job to decide whether they need a filter or not?

Comment: I don't completely understand your question, lists in python can have any kind of objects in them: `a = ['a', 5, int, (lambda:1+2), map] ; 5 in a -> True  ; 'a' in a -> True`

Comment: The thing is we don't know what could be in the list, the thing that you're checking for membership could be absolutely anything, and I would like for it to be in the list. Does that help?

Comment: ah, well not if you cast it to a list but an object that overloads `__contains__` can simulate containing every possible value.

Comment: Good idea!!!!! Life saver mate, props! @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need a list-like object, claiming that it contains any object.

You need to define a [list-like class](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types).

The simplest solution I can think about is a dirty hack:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return True
```

then  for any value assigned to `anyValue`:

```
>>> anyValue in MyList([])
True
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you just want to mock the `__contains__` operator. So maybe something like:

```
class MockList(list):
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return True
```